# How to select namespace from Consul

Tags: python, consul, service-discovery, hashicorp, consul-health-check

I have ent. Consul installed and it has multiple namespaces.
I want to use Python module to query specified namespace. Basically if I have namespaces: ns_1, ns_2. I want get the services and respective meta for ns_1 and ns_2 individually.
The input parameter would be the namespace (ns_1/ns_2).

—Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to StckOverflow. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It is a good practice to show some code depicting the approach you tried and give more details of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.